# Unable to display blob along with other data from table SPRING SQL JAVA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a table that contains :
"id" as a Primary key of type bigint(20) 
"cv" of type longblob
"info" of type varchar(255) latin1_swedish_ci

I'm trying to display the info and the blob. I used the findall from CrudRepository, but I get this error on the console

*Invalid stream header: 25504446*

and this on the browser :

*Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize*

If i remove the cv from the display it works fine just like this

```
[{"id":2,"info":"firstname_lastname"}]
```

I just want to display the info and a downloadable/viewable cv next to it. How can I do that ?

Comment: Can you insert the pojo that you map to?

Comment: can you show us the entity mapping class?